# With pydantic 1.10.14 Generic not displayed properly in fatsapi swagger docs

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to implement Generic with counted response (pydantic 1.10.14) so it displayed properly in fastapi swagger docs:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

M = TypeVar("M")


class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str


class NewCountedResults(BaseModel, Generic[M]):
    count: int
    results: list[M]


@app.get('/', response_model=NewCountedResults[User])
async def index():
    ...
```

It does not display User schema:

[image]

It displays properly with pydantic v2. How to fix it for pydantic 1.10.14?

Comment: Unfortunately, directly controlling the display of response model in Swagger isn't supported in Pydantic 1.10 or earlier. You need update Pydantic at least to 1.11.2 for offer more flexibility for customizing.